# Mysql within Node/Typesccript

Tags: mysql, node.js, typescript, unit-testing, clean-architecture

im' trying to get data from mysql database, here in my repository implementation, i defined my class who talks to the database bellow:

```
 async getParkingSpaces(): Promise<ParkingSpaceDTO[]> {

   const query = "SELECT no_place, place_type, occupied FROM parking_space;"
   return this.datasource.query(query,(err: Error, result: Object[]) => {
        if(err) {
            console.log(err)
        }else {
           console.log(result)
        }
    })
}
```

and here is my configure class for mysql :

```
export class MysqlConnection {

private static instance: MysqlConnection | null
private connection: mysql.Connection

constructor() {
     this.connection = mysql.createConnection({
        host:'localhost',
        user: 'root',
        password: 'root',
         port: 8889,
        database: 'parkingdb',
    })
    this.connect()
}

static getInstance() {
    if(!MysqlConnection.instance) {

        MysqlConnection.instance = new MysqlConnection()
    }
    return MysqlConnection.instance
}

private connect() {
    this.connection.connect((err:mysql.MysqlError) => {
        if(err) {
            console.log(`Error while connecting`)
            return
        }
       console.log(`connected as ${this.connection.threadId}`)
    })
}
public query(query:string, callback: Function):any {
    this.connection.query(query,  (error, results: Object[], fields:[]) => {
        if(error) return new QueryError()
        if(results.length === 0) callback("there is no records")
        callback(null, results)
    })
}
```

}

But when i run my unit test i get undefined instead of array of data. What i missed up here ?

Comment: is your `query` method returning anything? Looks like its just executing the callback

Comment: no my query mehtod doesn't return anything

Comment: what I mean is your query method has no return value, is that intentional?

Comment: normally i want to return a value. so what i have to do to fix it?